# Connect to Exchange - Getting Started Tutorial?

Tags: c#, c++, exchange-server

I need to connect to an Exchange-Server and to read some values, that a third party application stores there (BlackBerry Enterprise Server).

In my understanding I need to use CDO with C++ (C# doesn't seem to work this well in this regard). Is that right? I tried searching a little, but there seems to be lot of different approaches with a lot of different APIs and the whole topic confuses me a little.

Can anyone point me to some resources or tell me where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out www.slipstick.com - Sue Mosher's a Exchange Fan and has a great site - lots about CDO, MAPI, development, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys!
However I ended up downloading a little tool called MFCMapi from [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/MFCMAPI) and using the provided source code as a guide on how to do things.

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options based on the version of Exchange you are using.

**If you are running Exchange 2007**
Exchange Web Services - Language agnostic approach to communicating with Exchange and the primary method moving forward.  Googling EWS will return lots of good hits with tutorials and information in addition to the numerous books.

[An example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408521.aspx)

**If you are running Exchange 2003 or earlier**
WebDAV is a simple way to access Exchange as Marc recommend.  There are lots of good tutorials on the web for it as well.  It is also language agnostic like EWS.

[Dan's WebDAV 101 Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/default.aspx) - a blog I've used in the past for WebDAV & EWS info.

**Any version of Exchange**
If C++ is an option, there's also MAPI.  If you're not familiar with MAPI programming, it's going to be a little bit of a learning curve, but you can do just about anything to a mailbox and it's contents.  MAPI isn't supported in C#.

Answer (score 2):

It's been at least three years since I worked on this problem, but it seemed to me like the best solution was C# with WebDAV. Rather than try to explain code I don't really remember, here's a [link to a tutorial](http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/) I wrote at the time. Definitely check out the links at the end, I remember they were very helpful in understanding how the technology worked.